# Simple, concise way to express "tomorrow at 10:30am" using Java standard libraries

Tags: java, datetime

Using only standard java 1.5 calls, I'm looking for a concise and simple way to get a java Date object for a specific time, say the next 10:30am that occurs in the future. This will generally be tomorrow at 10:30am, but it may be today at 10:30am if the current time is, say, 8am.

Efficiency is only a secondary or tertiary concern.

It seems like there must be a more graceful way to do it than manually constructing a Calendar object and setting each of its fields in a separate method call.

Using SimpleDateFormat would be fine with a format string like "HH:mm", but I don't see a clever way to get it to adjust to the next future 10:30am rather than simply today's 10:30am.  Plus, those try/catch blocks are a bit tacky.

Is there really no simple one or two line way to express this?

Comment: "adjust to the next future 10:30am" - that is easy for a human, but not for a computer! That's why the world needs programmers.

Comment: A thought experiment.  Imagine two boxes.  They are very large.  One box is labelled 'concise and simple.'  The other box contains everything related to dealing with date and time in the Java programming language.  :(

Comment: @Affe clicked this link to say something similar. +1

Answer (score 5):

There is no convienence method in the standard API, you need a sequence like

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

Date next = cal.getTime();
if (today.after(next)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

You should just put this into an utility class.

Comment: Like: `public Date nextDateAt(int hour, int minute );`

Comment: It's not bad certainly.  I'm hoping someone can come up with something even more succinct

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which provides a better date/time implementation than the JDK, you can get the next 10:30 instance using this code

```
final LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime().withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfDay(0);
final LocalDateTime tenThirty;
if (now.getHourOfDay() <= 10 && now.getMinuteOfHour() <= 30) {
    tenThirty = now.withHourOfDay(10).withMinuteOfHour(30);
} else {
    tenThirty = now.plusDays(1).withHourOfDay(10).withMinuteOfHour(30);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with Joda.  But due to space considerations (I'm on android) I would prefer to stick with the standard java library calls.

Comment: Not sure if commons-lang is on your classpath, the `DateUtils` class has useful convinience methods for dealing with `java.util.Date`